# Quill and different options for contexts

Tags: scala, orm, cassandra, quill, quill-scala

using Quill+Scala in one project I am working with, but I find Quill's scala documentation very poor.

In their website, there are basically three context types for interacting with Cassandra: CassandraSynchContext, CassandraAsynchContext, and CassandraStreamContext. While names are suggestive, I need all the information I can get. E.g., what does stream mean here? What are the properties in async calls, how to get exceptions, etc.

So, in a sense, I am interested in any reliable documentation pointing out the key differences between all three contexts. Any help is useful at this point.

Thanks.